# How to Import images with IMPORTXML

Tags: image, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Import from site: https://weather.interia.com/long-term-forecast-chicago,cId,49700

I'm trying to import a list of image URL's in the following class:

[image]

URL in Cell `A1`

I've tried using

```
=IMPORTXML($A$1, "//img/@src")
```

While this does import some images, it does not import the desired images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best you can do would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE("https://weather.interia.com/i/icons-bg-light-2/"&ROW(A1:A60)&".png",3))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE("https://weather.interia.com/i/icons-bg-light-2/"&
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(IMPORTXML(
 "https://weather.interia.com/long-term-forecast-chicago,cId,49700", 
 "//span[@class='weather-forecast-longterm-list-entry-forecast-phrase']"), { 
 "Showers"            , 12;
 "Partly sunny"       , 3;
 "Cold"               , 31;
 "Mostly cloudy"      , 6;
 "Dreary"             , 8;
 "Cloudy"             , 7;
 "Mostly cloudy"      , 8;
 "Mostly sunny"       , 2;
 "Intermittent clouds", 4;
 "Freezing rain"      , 26;
 "Flurries"           , 19;
 "Sunny"              , 1;
 "Hazy sunshine"      , 5;
 "Snow"               , 22}, 2, 0))&".png", 3))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Ok, is there no way to import it so that it updates daily in the same order as the weather is reporting?

Comment: @depends how badly you want it. answer updated. note that you will need to extend the database next period with missing images in that vlookup

Comment: Found their source for icon mapping here: https://developer.accuweather.com/weather-icons

with that i'll use this, thanks again!

Comment: @PeterChabot nice find